# in a Hilbert space, $f(y)=\|x-y\|$ is minimal for $u$ being the orthogonal projection.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $(X,\left<\cdot ,\cdot \right>)$ a Hilbert space. Let $Y$ a closed subspace of $X$. I wish prove that $$\inf_{y\in Y}\|x-y\|=\|x-p\|.$$ where $p$ the the orthogonal projection of $x$, i.e. $p$ is the only element of $Y$ s.t. $\left<p,y\right>=\left<x,y\right>$ for all $y\in Y$.

**Attempts**

We have that
\begin{align*}
\|x-y\|^2&=\left<x,x\right>-2\left<x,y\right>+\left<y,y\right>\\
&=\left<x,x\right>-2\left<p,y\right>+\left<y,y\right>\\
&\underset{Cauchy-Schwartz}{\geq} \left<x,x\right>-2\sqrt{\left<p,p\right>\left<y,y\right>}+\left<y,y\right> 
\end{align*}
but I don't see how to continue...

Answer (score 1):

Since for all $y\in Y$, $$\left<x,y\right>=\left<p,y\right>,$$
you have that $$\left<x-p,y\right>=0,$$
for all $y\in Y$. Therefore,
$$\|x-y\|^2=\|x-p+p-y\|^2\underset{\left<x-p,p-y\right>=0}{=}\|x-p\|^2+\|p-y\|^2\geq \|x-p\|^2.$$